# Taylor polynomials in calculating limits , series and improper integrals

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{k} \left(2sin(1/k)-sin(2/k)\right)$

I have two questions : 
Why does $\sum_{k} 2sin(1/k)$ diverge ?
My attempt : because $sin (1/k)$ will look like $1/k$ when $k$ gets very large ,harmonic serie, is this correct ?

using Taylor formel : $2sin(\frac{2}{k}) = 2/k-\frac{1}{6k^{3}}+O(\frac{1}{k^{5}})$

I do find the right solution when I use this but I dont have any good understanding of why it works. I also don't understand how to operate with ordo (big O notation ) , like how do i decide when the restterm is very small ie dont effect my sum and when is it big?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you had to write $Ln(1+x)$ instead of $Ln(x)$.

Comment: I don't think you can use it when bounds are infinite, but with a substitution t=1/x you can
But I believe you get same result as if you do it without substitute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Taylor as you did :

$sin(t) = t-\frac{t^{3}}{6}+O(t^{5})$

$sin(\frac{1}{k}) = 1/k-\frac{1}{6k^{3}}+O(\frac{1}{k^{5}})$

$2sin(\frac{2}{k}) = 2/k-\frac{1}{6k^{3}}+O(\frac{1}{k^{5}})$

$\sum_{k} \left(2sin(1/k)-sin(2/k)\right)$=$
\sum \frac{1}{k^{3}}+O(\frac{1}{k^{5}})$ which converges / diverges if and only if  $\sum \frac{1}{k^{3}}$ converges / diverges.

Note : because $\sum \frac{1}{k^{3}}+O(\frac{1}{k^{5}})$ is positive serie , you can use the comparison test .

http://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf explains the big O notation in a simple way.

Answer (score 2):

For the simplicity for each natural $k$ put

$x_k=2\sin\frac 1k$ and $y_k=2\sin\frac 1k-\sin\frac 2k=2\sin \frac 1k(1-\cos\frac 1k).$

Since all numbers $x_k$ and $y_k$ are non-negative, we may use [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) of testing for the convergence of the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty y_k$.

Since the harmonic series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac 1k$ diverges and

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{x_k}{\frac 1k}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}t=1,$$

the series $\sum x_k$ diverges too.

Since the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{k^3}$ converges and

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{y_k}{\frac 1{k^3}}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t(1-\cos t)}{t^3}=
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{2\sin t\sin^2 (t/2)}{t^3}=
\lim_{t\to 0}2\frac{\sin t}t\frac {\sin (t/2)}t\frac {\sin (t/2)}t=\frac 12,$$

the series $\sum y_k$ converges too.

**Update**.

**Proposition.** For any natural $k$ let $y_k, z_k$ be real numbers such that $z_k-y_k=O(f(k))$ for some non-negative function $f $. Then

1) If a series $\sum f(k)$  converges then a series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty y_k$ converges iff series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty z_k$ converges.

2) If $z_k-y_k$ is negative for each $k$ and $z_k-y_k=\Theta(f(k))$ (this means that both  $z_k-y_k=O(f(k))$  and $f(k) =O(z_k-y_k)$) and one of the series  $\sum_{k=1}^\infty y_k$, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty z_k$ converges then the other series converges iff the series  $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k)$ converges.

*Proof*.

1) By the definition of $O(f(k))$, there exist constants $N$ and $C$ such that  $|z_k-y_k|\le Cf(k)$  for all $k>N$. Since the series $\sum f(k)$ converges, the series $\sum z_k-y_k$ converges (even absolutely), which implies the claim, beacuse a sum of two convergent series if convergent.

2) The implication $\Leftarrow$ follows from (1). To show the opposite implication remark that if both the series $\sum z_k$ and $\sum y_k$ converge, then their difference $\sum z_k-y_k$ also converges. Since $f(k) =O(z_k-y_k)$, there exist constants $N$ and $C$ such that  $f(k)\le C(z_k-y_k) $ for all $k>N$. Therefore the series $\sum f(k)$ converges.

Comment: Thanks but if you do it in my way using taylor approximation, how can you decide if the rest term is too small that it can be ignored or not ?

Comment: @Jacksoja I updated my answer.